# GUI tool to manage Samba shares on Raspberry Pi?

Tags: gui, raspberry-pi, samba

I recently discovered the Gnome Disk Utility available for Raspberry Pis, and it made working with USB drives easy like Windows.

Is there a similar utility that I can install on a Raspberry Pi to easily manage Samba?  Specifically, I am looking for:

- Easy to install (sudo apt-get blah)
- Easy to use and intuitive for a Windows user
- It works

I want to set up a couple of shares and have 1 user (or guest user) with read access, and another user with read/write access.  Nothing crazy.

I have nothing against the command line, but the command line is nonintuitive, prone to aging out and instructions stop working for no reason, and while there is potential there, I can never seem coerce any Linux community to figure out the right commands that I need.  And I'm usually trying to follow a tutorial.

I see that several packages are listed [here](https://www.samba.org/samba/GUI/), but aside from Webmin, they are all Samba clients, not configuration tools.  Webmin sounds cool, but looks like installing it is a rabbit hole.  I'll consider it, but I think that will take all next weekend (wasted this weekend trying to make a shared folder).